# SwiftUI Image component shrinks when resized

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I've been testing out SwiftUI and I guess most of you have too. I am having a weird issue, most probably a bug, but maybe someone else have found a workaround for it.

```
var body: some View {
    Image("profilepic")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
}
```

In a normal situation I'd expect that image to be resized and have big margins in the screen because I set the content mode to fit, if I'd use fill it will just fill the whole screen.

The fit is working fine, but the image is not keeping the aspect ratio, it shrinks.

If you have encounter this issue and know how to fix it let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also having this issue, looks like this is beta bug.
I recommend to leave it as it is and wait for a fix from Apple.

If you really need to have correct Image you can create custom view struct for a SwiftUI

```
struct FixedImage: UIViewRepresentable {

    var imageName: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIImageView {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: imageName))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return imageView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIImageView, context: Context) {
        uiView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Was having the same problem trying to shrink an image down to a thumbnail for a list view... nothing was working. I also got errors trying the suggested fix from Lex above. So I modified it... Extended View Protocol with a function to calculate and return the image aspect ratio...

```
extension View {
    func calcImageAspectRatio(_ imageName: String) -> Length?
    {
        if let image = UIImage(named: imageName) {
            let size = image.size
            return size.width / size.height
        }
        return nil
    }
}

extension ExerciseList {
    struct ExerciseCell : View {
        let exercise: Exercise

        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                Image(exercise.visuals)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(calcImageAspectRatio(exercise.visuals), contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                Text(exercise.title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case, default image us not shrunk but changing image in Image() was resulted shrunk image. Now it works with this aspect ratio calculation, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This solved the shrink problem

```
Image(uiImage:self.selectedImage)
.resizable()
.aspectRatio(self.selectedImage.size, contentMode: .fit)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public var body: some View {

    let size = UIImage(named: "at")!.size
    let aspect = size.width / size.height

    let img = Image("at")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(aspect, contentMode: .fill)
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
        .clipShape(Circle())
        .shadow(radius: 10)
    return img
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is great workaround. But if more complex Views you will have an error "Closure containing a declaration cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'". So you will need to calculate aspect on flight(without variables)

Comment: @DenFav could you provide a code example of complex View that that you described?

Comment: Cannot send it to private chat somewhy var body: some View {
        let size = UIImage(named: car.imageName)!.size
        let aspect = size.width / size.height
        
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            Image(car.imageName)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(aspect, contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .shadow(radius: 10) }}

Comment: @DenFav you're expecting to align this image top left, right? How about [this](https://www.friendpaste.com/1FwgNkt8NzGrqDtS0rGViH)? Just manipulate position of image with spacers if it's ignoring alignment parameters

Comment: @DenFav btw if you change Image to Text in your example nothing changes it still will be center vertically and horizontally, so maybe it's not an Image issue but View's structure

Comment: This part should place the image over another View in top left corner. And yes, I agree that your approach is working, but possibility it will be much easier to perform when Apple will fix automatic contentMode = .fit. It was working in the Sessions, but doesn't in xCode beta

Comment: @DenFav it's been a while since Apple released swift and Xcode still not provide tools for code generation, syntax highlight and proper autocompletion. Hope you're right, I'm not as optimistic as you and don't have faith that Apple fix something :)

Comment: That have used this modifier in their first Session on WWDC, and they have specific modifier in code(it just doesn't work). So that 's why I am optimistic to this functionality